# git-http-backend not accepting push options

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git push -o myoption` but I'm getting the following error:

```
 fatal: the receiving end does not support push options
```

Apparently I have to set the following config option to turn it on:

```
  git config --global receive.advertisePushOptions true
```

But that did not work (I've tried it on the server with and without `sudo`).

On the server end I have a custom CGI running `git-http-backend`. Is there another place where to set the `receive.advertisePushOptions` option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I wasn't using the correct `git-http-backend` binary that supports push options. This feature is not supported by Git 2.6.

Once the correct binary was used, both local and global `git config` worked.